# Can I run Jasmine tests through Mocha

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mocha.js

As the title says, I'd like to be able to able to run Jasmine tests using Mocha on node. As an experiment I've installed Jasmine and Mocha and ran

```
jasmine examples
```

to install the examples.

Running Jasmine runs the tests as expected:

```
$ ./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js
Started
.....


5 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.012 seconds
```

But running the tests in Mocha doesn't work:

```
$ ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha spec/jasmine_examples/PlayerSpec.js

0 passing (11ms)
5 failing

1) Player
   should be able to play a Song:
   ReferenceError: expect is not defined
   at Context.<anonymous> (spec\jasmine_examples\PlayerSpec.js:14:5)
```

etc

Similarly if I try and add a call to jasmine.createSpy() into a test, it works fine under Jasmine but under Mocha it reports

```
ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined
```

May be I shouldn't be entirely surprised but as I'm new to this Javascript world could someone explain to me either how to get it working or why it doesn't work?

In case anyone is wondering why I want to do this, as a team we're using Jasmine but I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE. This doesn't understand Jasmine tests so I have to manually create run configurations to run specific tests. If I could get them to run under Mocha, I could use the built-in Mocha support and just click on the little arrows IntelliJ puts next to Mocha tests.

Answer (score 3):

There are superficial resemblances between Jasmine and Mocha (`describe`, `it`, etc.) but there are a lot of differences that have to be bridged if you want to have a suite run under both. You cannot take a Jasmine suite and *generally* expect it to work in Mocha without modifications. Jasmine is not designed to run Mocha tests and Mocha is not designed to run Jasmine tests.

For instance Mocha cannot do anything with `jasmine.createSpy()`. It does not even have an equivalent for it built into Mocha itself. If you were to *port* your suite to Mocha (i.e. abandon Jasmine in favor of Mocha), you'd have to use a library like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to provide similar functionality. If you want to have your suite run both in Mocha and Jasmine, then you might be able to bridge the gap with a wrapper library that detects which runner it is running under and calls `jasmine.createSpy()` or a Sinon equivalent as needed but with any non-trivial test suite the work required would be substantial. (And frankly, there's no project I work on where I could justify the expense.)

You'd also have to use a library like [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) to provide `expect`.

Comment: I appreciate there are significant differences. What I'm struggling to understand is what exactly is the Mocha runner doing that stops it seeing the jasmine methods? If these were Java framework then so long as Mocha  and Jasmine were on the classpath, it would probably work ok. I'm struggling to understand enough about what's going on work out why it doesn't just load up the relevant javascript files and call the Jasmine methods.

Comment: When you run `jasmine`, the CLI tool deliberately manipulates the global space to put a `jasmine` object that has methods like `createSpy`. Same with `describe`, `it`, and anything that is not part of the default global space provided by Node but automagically appears there. When you run `mocha` at the CLI, Mocha does the same for the functionalities it provides. Merely *installing* Jasmine or Mocha does not cause every single file executing in your project to see Jasmine or Mocha's globals, you *have* to use the respective CLI tools they provide.

Comment: Does it indeed. That makes sense with the behaviour i'm seeing. Adding --require jasmine at least gets the expects methods working but not the jasmine.spy methods. I'll have to start digging around in the source.